# Combine separate datasets into one table by time series, adding new rows in where only one table exists

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to combine a few different datasets to be more easily analysed.

They all show different things with different timestamps that I want to analyse against each other!

So like, maybe at one time stamp only one thing will popup as an example.

The dataframes look something like this,

```
<bound method NDFrame.to_clipboard of    id                       user_id  sentiment  magnitude     created
0  10  cPL1Fg7BqRXvSFKeU1mJT7KCCTq2       -0.1        0.1  1601820360
1  11  cPL1Fg7BqRXvSFKeU1mJT7KCCTq2       -0.8        0.8  1601820365
2  12  cPL1Fg7BqRXvSFKeU1mJT7KCCTq2       -0.2        0.2  1601900938
3  13  cPL1Fg7BqRXvSFKeU1mJT7KCCTq2       -0.2        0.2  1601900956
4  14  cPL1Fg7BqRXvSFKeU1mJT7KCCTq2        0.2        0.2  1601900971>

<bound method NDFrame.to_clipboard of      angry  disgusted  fearful    happy  neutral      sad  surprised  \
0  0.00620    0.00101  0.00445  0.01214  0.94268  0.03007    0.00345   
1  0.02152    0.00459  0.01222  0.05745  0.85061  0.04810    0.00552   
2  0.01343    0.00362  0.00807  0.04311  0.88810  0.03633    0.00733   
3  0.02397    0.02335  0.00200  0.16026  0.74643  0.04056    0.00344   
4  0.01191    0.00462  0.01357  0.08153  0.88545  0.00083    0.00209   

      created  
0  1603076108  
1  1603076408  
2  1603076708  
3  1603077008  
4  1603077308  >
```

Using concatenate, it seems to be only combining where both values may exist. I want to have each in the dataframe. Thanks!

Comment: I have a feeling the way to tackle this is with `join(how='outer')` :https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't try solutions to help you based on what you provided. We need a small toy-sized input case and the corresponding expected output.